# How to access Spree's link_to_cart function from main rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am building a spree shop into an exiting Rails application, and I need to access `link_to_cart` from outside of the Spree engine.

`link_to_cart` can be found here: [`spree/core/app/helpers/spree/base_helper.rb`](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/e584c7bfa66e0827d3088f4ff8a51a0b09723803/core/app/helpers/spree/base_helper.rb)

Since I have modified the styling in `link_to_cart`, I also created:

```
  #helpers/spree/base_helper_decorator.rb
  module Spree
    module BaseHelper
      def link_to_cart(text = nil)
      text = text ? h(text) : Spree.t('cart')
      css_class = nil

      if simple_current_order.nil? or simple_current_order.item_count.zero?
        text = "#{text}: (#{Spree.t('empty')})"
        css_class = 'empty'
      else
        text = "<i class='fa fa-shopping-cart'></i> #{text}: (#{simple_current_order.item_count})  <span class='amount'>#{simple_current_order.display_total.to_html}</span>".html_safe
        css_class = 'full'
      end

      link_to text.html_safe, spree.cart_path, :class => "cart-info #{css_class} btn btn-small btn-success pull-right", style: "margin-left:10px;"
    end
  end
end
```

I have tried doing stuff like Spree::BaseHelper.link_to_cart outside of the engine, but I keep getting `undefined local variable or method 'link_to_cart'`

I found this on a [different StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797690/rails-3-1-better-way-to-expose-an-engines-helper-within-the-client-app), and it seems promising, but I'm not sure how to modify it for my needs:

```
module MyEngine
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    initializer 'my_engine.action_controller' do |app|
      ActiveSupport.on_load :action_controller do
        helper MyEngine::ImportantHelper
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi @Abram , I have the same problem but the solution wont work for me. Any tip?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, thanks Ben for getting me on the right track. Here was my solution:

```
# class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Order
   include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Auth
   helper Spree::BaseHelper
   helper Spree::StoreHelper
```

**Update**

I ran into an issue with `current_store` being undefined outside of the engine. I'm not sure how to solve this properly, but in the meantime I've just added the following to stop spree from calling current_store:

```
module Spree
  module Core
    module ControllerHelpers
      module Order
        def current_order_params
          { currency: current_currency, guest_token: cookies.signed[:guest_token], store_id: Spree::Store.first, user_id: try_spree_current_user.try(:id) }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Also `helper Spree::StoreHelper` seems to no longer be required to display the cart button and current orders..

Comment: Ahha, the fabled stackoverflow answer with the exact answer you needed! Where did you add the second code snippet please? I tried orders controller decorator but no cigar :(

Comment: Cannot recall. Try lib

Comment: Hmm no luck. Tried various combinations within app and no luck too. How strange.

Comment: Adding the current_order_params function to the application controller and manually specifying current_currency is working for me for now!

Comment: Thanks for this! It got me on the right track. It seems some updates to spree made it so you have to add `include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Common` . This changes the way your entire app is rendered, though.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do two things

1. Create your override
2. Make your override accessible within the main
   app

Step 1: My Spree overrides are in the overrides folder in my main app. The override should call `module_eval` on the module that you are decorating.

```
#overrides/base_helper_decorator.rb
Spree::BaseHelper.module_eval do

  def link_to_cart(text = nil)
    #Your customizations here
  end

end
```

Step 2: Add one of the lines below to your main app ApplicationController to access your decorated helper.

```
helper_method :link_to_cart # Add only the link_to_cart method 

helper 'spree/base'         # Add all methods (your decoration plus the default methods) 
                            # from the Spree BaseHelper module to your main app
```

Comment: Not sure why, but after doing everything I am still getting undefined local variable or method `link_to_cart'

Answer (score 2):

There have been some updates since Abram left his answer. It got me on the right track but I had a few hiccups. The main one was `current_currency` being undefined.

`application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Order
  include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Auth
  include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Store
  include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Common
  helper Spree::BaseHelper
```

I overrode the Spree navbar and used the one for my main app.

It started working when I added `include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Common`. Unfortunately, this renders all views through the spree `spree_application.html.erb` layout. You may have to override and tinker a bit with this view.

Also, all of the css comes from spree at this point. You'll have to move your custom css into the spree namespace and @import it.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to include the right helpers in your main application outside the engine too. In the upcoming version 3.2.0 of spree I just had to add:

```
# class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Store
  include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Order
  include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Auth
```

to my ApplicationController to make `link_to_cart` work everywhere. You'll need to include more then one helper class, because for example `current_store` (used by other helpers) is defined in `Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Store`, so add that too to get rid of any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your main_app to access the cart.

`<%= link_to "Cart", spree.cart_path %>`