# Spree link_to_cart not working when I mount the engine at /shop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm using Spree 2.3.3.

When I mount the engine on `/shop`, the link_to_cart wont work and the cart wont show on any page.

I would like the cart to show on every page (including the non-engine Spree views)

## routes

```
mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/shop'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Its probably everuthing ok with app, but routes.
Maybe you should include some helpers to your non-engine controllers.
Did you see something like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296965/how-to-access-sprees-link-to-cart-function-from-main-rails-app ?

Comment: @Ablebeam yes, but It didn't work for me... Im very stuck with this.

Comment: Can you post the view which you are attempting to use `link_to_cart`?