# Undefined method error for helper method on view in rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines, view-helpers

I am facing the following problem: in my application I use engines. Let's say I have a shop engine. Within that shop engine I have two controllers: carts_controller and products_controller and their helpers: carts_helper and products_helper.

Now on my `views/shop/products/index.html.erb` view, I try to call the method cart_action which is defined in `helpers/shop/carts_helper.rb`. However, unfortunately I get a `` undefined method `cart_action' for #<#<Class:0x007fb3627af090>:0x007fb3627aab08> `` when I do this. When I place the same method in `helpers/shop/products_helper.rb` I do not get this message and the method works fine.... Why can't I use the method from carts_helper, but can I use the method from products_helper? In a normal rails app I can use any helper method on any view, right?

It might have to do something with the namespacing i.e. the helper files are not in `helpers` but in `helpers/shop` however [this helps prevent conflicts with helpers from other engines or apps...](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#generating-an-article-resource)

```
module Shop
  module CartsHelper
      def cart_action(package_id)
        #some code
      end
  end
end
```

How I call it on `shop/products/index.html.erb`:

```
<%= cart_action(package['id']) %>
```

Could it have to do with the fact that I inherit functionality for my applications_controller from my main app?:

```
class Shop::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
end
```

instead of

```
module Shop
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  end
end
```

FWIW my routes for this engine looks like:

```
Shop::Engine.routes.draw do
    resources :products, only: [:index]
    # shopping cart
    resource :cart, only: [:show] do
        put 'add/:package_id', to: 'carts#add', as: :add_to
        put 'remove/:package_id', to: 'carts#remove', as: :remove_from
    end

end
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Note: I do not want to use my helper method in my main app, rather just on another view in the same engine.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the ApplicationHelper, only view-specific helpers are accessible to the view. Since this is your product-related view, only the ApplicationHelper + ProductsHelper are accessible. So the solution is to either move this method to ProductsHelper or to ApplicationHelper.

Comment: Thanks @MarcusTres, learned something new today :) I found two other options that work for me as well, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29734454/3519981).

Answer (score 2):

I found two ways to make the methods available to other views as well:

By creating an initializer in my `/my_engine/lib/my_engine/engine.rb` file as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9641149/3519981

Or by including `helper :all` in my `controllers/myengine/application_controller.rb` file as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1179900/3519981

Note both will make all the helpers available in the main application as well. For me that is not a problem (at the moment).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if anyone here has the same issue as me, but basically after I made a new custom helper and it wasn't accessible in a view, all I had to do was restart the rails server.  I felt pretty silly after realizing that, well also relieved :-)